# basic Ruby on Rails undefined method issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I'm a relative amateur to RoR developing (about a month's experience) and I've been referencing variables from different controllers with no issues up until this point. I'm developing a CMS for a blog and I cannot get the blog's author's username to appear on the index or show pages. I receive a "undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass" error. However, I can get the ID. Can anyone help point out the errors in my code? I would greatly appreciate it.

This is the blog model:

```
    class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :post, :title

    has_one :users
    belongs_to :user

        end
```

This is the blog controller's show and index section:

```
    def index
      @users = User.all
      @blogs = Blog.all


     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @blogs }
       end
         end

       # GET /blogs/1
       # GET /blogs/1.json
   def show
     @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
     @users = User.all      

         respond_to do |format|
           format.html # show.html.erb
           format.json { render json: @blog }
         end
      end
```

Here is the index.html.erb code:

```
     <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
       <tr>
        <td><%= blog.title %></td>
        <td><%= blog.post %></td>
        <td><%= blog.user.username %></td> #blog.user_id works perfectly here.
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', blog %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm:'sure?'} %></td>
       </tr>
         <% end %>
```

This is the code for the show.html.erb file:

```
      <p>
      <b>Title:</b>
       <%= @blog.title %>
       </p>

       <p>
       <b>Author:</b>
        <%= @blog.user.username %>
       </p>

       <p>
       <b>Post:</b>
       <%= @blog.post %>
       </p>
```

Here is the create code in the blog controller:

```
      Here is the create code:

    # POST /blogs
    # POST /blogs.json
        def create
         @blog = Blog.new(params[:blog])
         @blog.user_id = current_user

           respond_to do |format|
            if @blog.save
              format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render json: @blog, status: :created, location: @blog }
               else
                format.html { render action: "new" }
                format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
          end
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `has_one: users` be singular? In other words, class Blog should have `has_one: user`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :post, :title

    #has_one :users // remove this line of code..
    belongs_to :user

end
```

Also check, May be user_id is pointing to a user record which doesn't exists..

Answer (score 0):

Please check your blogs table and see whether user_id is present or not in every created blog.

also check your user model do changes as per your required association.

if you are using one-to-one relationship then your user model should have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :blog
end
```

or If you are using one-to-many relationship then the user model should have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs
end
```

Change your blog model with following.

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :post, :title
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Try to create new blog by adding following changes in your blogs controller .

```
def create
 @blog = Blog.new(params[:blog])
 @blog.user_id = current_user.id

 respond_to do |format|
  if @blog.save
   format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
   format.json { render json: @blog, status: :created, location: @blog }
  else
   format.html { render action: "new" }
   format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Does your users table have username column?